# How to call this.function in a same file where we create the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

in my project we tried to build protractor framework. so in js file we create some functions using this.functionname syntax and we want to re use that function when it required in the function which is also present in the same file. for clear view i gave the code below...

### this is my reusable functions JS file

```
var fb=require("H:/workspace/Protractor_PT/src/pages/FbPage.js");
var action=function(){
    
    beforeAll(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
        browser.get("https://facebook.com");
        login();
    });
    
    this.clickElement=function(element){
        element.click();
    }
    
    this.enterText=function(element,text){
        element.sendKeys(text);
    }
    
    var login=function(){
        action.enterText(fb.emailField(),"dfdsfds");
        action.enterText(fb.passfield(),"dfdsfds");
    }
}
module.login=new action();
```

on top, you can find the functions this.clickElement and this.enterText.. i want to use those functions in the other function named login.. but when i called those functions with "action.enterText" - action is the main global variable of the file... i'm getting below error

### Error Log

```
 Message:
    Failed: action.enterText is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: action.enterText is not a function
        at login (H:\workspace\Protractor_PT\src\pages\Utilities.js:19:13)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (H:\workspace\Protractor_PT\src\pages\Utilities.js:7:3)
        at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
        at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    From: Task: Run beforeAll in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
        at Jasmine.execute (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:200:12)
        at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:132:15
        at Function.promise (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at new action (H:\workspace\Protractor_PT\src\pages\Utilities.js:4:2)
        at Object.<anonymous> (H:\workspace\Protractor_PT\src\pages\Utilities.js:23:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.049 seconds

[20:22:32] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:22:32] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[20:22:32] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[20:22:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: when the inner functions are created the `action` is unknown to them. you probably has to do a local variable which points the the action function and use it instead of action.    like, first line of action function do this: localAction = this; then use `localAction.enterText`

Comment: kk..i will try and update it

Comment: @V.Sambor - your comment seems like the answer - you should avoid answering the question in a comment and actually use an answer.

Comment: it is working...it is very helpful to me.. and also i have one more problem.. if want to use that login function how can i use that..

Comment: Ok I will answer properly :)

Comment: can you please answer this one.. " if i want to use that login function in another js file how can i use that."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case when the inner functions are created the variable **action** is unknown to them.
You can do a local variable which points to the parent function and use it instead of the **action**.

You can do something like this:

```
var fb = require('H:/workspace/Protractor_PT/src/pages/FbPage.js')
var action = function () {
    var localAction = this;    // <<<-----------   HERE
    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
        browser.get('https://facebook.com')
        login()
    })
    this.clickElement = function (element) {
        element.click()
    }
    this.enterText = function (element, text) {
        element.sendKeys(text)
    }
    var login = function () {
        localAction.enterText(fb.emailField(), 'dfdsfds') // Use local var here.
        localAction.enterText(fb.passfield(), 'dfdsfds')
    }
}
module.login = new action()
```